# Angular selectbox not selecting default value

Tags: angularjs

So I recently started to work with Angular, and have been rather questioned about how the selectbox I have isn't working how I expected it to work.

The HTML generated is:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" name="status" ng-model="data.user.user.active">
    <option value="? number:1 ?" selected="selected"></option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: status in lists.states -->
    <option ng-repeat="status in lists.states" value="1" ng-selected="true" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Active - 1</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: status in lists.states -->
    <option ng-repeat="status in lists.states" value="2" ng-selected="false" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Inactive - 1</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: status in lists.states --></select>
```

I was wondering why this is generating :

```
<option value="? number:1 ?" selected="selected"></option>
```

The code I have for this is:

```
<select class="form-control" name="status" ng-model="data.user.user.active">
      <option ng-repeat="status in lists.states" value="{{ status.id }}" ng-selected="{{ status.id === data.user.user.active }}">
             {{ cs.fields.userStatus[status.status] }}
      </option>
</select>
```

array of lists.states :

```
[
   0 => 
     ['status' => 'inactive', 'id' => 2],
   1 => 
     ['status' => 'active', 'id' => 1]
]
```

Method that grabs the states:

```
// Load States List
AdminFactory.getStates().then((result) => {
     $scope.lists.states = result.states;
     console.log(result.states);
});
```

Oh and this is written in Angular 1, and cannot be updated to Angular 2 despite it's improvements at this moment.

Comment: I think you have syntax problems, look at [here](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/) or If you want to set default value then use `ng-init`.

Comment: Try changing to `ng-selected="status.id === data.user.user.active"`

Comment: @Sai your solution seemed to have worked, tho I noticed another bug in my system, where it kinda looks like the HTML is generated before all the data was received "the states are loaded in seperately" and are not send over with the initial method. I have added the code that grabs the states above now too.

Comment: when you are using angular's `ng-selected` you can write javascript expressions in it like I did above. But, if you use HTML's `selected` you can't do that. So, incase of `selected` write like `selected="{{ status.id === data.user.user.active }}"`.

Comment: You can simply use ng-init like this

`<select ng-init="somethingHere = options[0]" 
        ng-model="somethingHere" 
        ng-options="option.name for option in options">
</select>`

Comment: What is your exact problem right now? Even if the states are loaded after the HTML, they are automatically updated.

Comment: The problem has been solved, it was a mix of your answer, I was using ng-selected and that does not accept the curly brackets, and I had to change when I loaded in my data externally. It now all works, somehow it did not update the selectboxes even though the external data was loaded at a certain time. This may be due to the construction someone build around this.

Comment: I just checked with someone else, we're using a modified version of Angular and it looks like it was a bug that it didn't work. But many thanks after all, the ng-selected and HTML selected information really helped me with it aswell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sai I figured out my error had to do with using the curly brackets inside the `ng-selected="statement"`, since this is an Angular attribute it can read out variables directly and only have to the curly brackets when using HTML's `selected="{{ statement }}"` version.